# How load 3 google adsense in the same time - ASP NET

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, load, adsense

I've in my website 3 adsense. I would like to load them "together", they must appers on the page in the same time.

right now, in my web site they are loading like:

```
<html>
    <javascript>
    adsense1 <- Load Second
    </Script>

    <javascript>
    adsense2 <- Load First
    </Script>

    <javascript>
    adsense3 <- Load third
    </Script>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing to do with Classic ASP.  Please retag.

Answer (score 0):

First what I'd suggest is - if you are using synchronous version of AdSense code, upgrade it to asynchronous.

About the asynchronous ad code
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3221666?hl=en

Also, if they are placed one by one, for example:

```
[300x250]
[300x250]
[300x250]
```

You could "merge" them in bigger format, and use one ad snippet:

```
[300x600]
```

(EDIT, to clarify: When I say "merge", I mean "create new `300x600` unit in your http://www.google.com/adsense dashboard and use that code instead of 3 x `300x250`.)

That way they **will** absolutely definitely and ultimately load at the same time :)